# Twitter API v2 endpoints authentication error

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to pull tweets using Twitter Developer API V2. My access level is Elevated. This is how my code looks like:

```
import tweepy

consumerKey = "*********mc7K"
consumerSecret = "*******BZNB"
accessToken = "*****-****9eeT"
accessTokenSecret = "****sWAa"
bearerToken="****VRqn"

client = tweepy.Client(wait_on_rate_limit=True, bearer_token=bearerToken, consumer_key=consumerKey, consumer_secret=consumerSecret, access_token=accessToken, access_token_secret=accessTokenSecret)

tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=search_query, tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at'], max_results=10)
```

This throws me an error saying:

> When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must
> use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a
> Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.

But if I use `tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=search_query, tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at'])`, it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

[Tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_all_tweets) - [TWITTER API V2 REFERENCE](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all)

```
Client.search_all_tweets
```

> This endpoint is only available to those users who have been approved
> for the Academic Research product track.
>
> The full-archive search endpoint returns the complete history of
> public Tweets matching a search query; since the first Tweet was
> created March 26, 2006.
> The Tweets returned by this endpoint count towards the Project-level Tweet cap.